# How am i to assign 90 seats to 40 boys and 50 girls without repetition in java

Tags: java

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
        int size = 90;

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
        for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }

        Random rand = new Random();
        while(list.size() > 0) {
            int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
            System.out.println("BOY: "+list.remove(index));
            System.out.println("Girl: "+list.remove(index));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have done, and am still getting Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 45, Size: 45.`
what can I do to resolve this.

Comment: use an iterator

Comment: You are generating a random index based on the size of the list once, but then removing an item at that index twice.  You only have a guarantee that something exists at that index on the first remove.

Comment: A better way to "pick a series of random list elements" is not to pick randomly at all.  Instead, shuffle the list and then just iterate through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 45, Size: 45`.

Reason for that is you are accessing index `45` in size of `45` list. Your list size getting decrease when you randomly remove element from the list. So this- `Index: 45, Size: 45` will change each and every time when you run the program.

As a solution you can change:

```
int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
```

To:

```
int index = rand.nextInt(list.size()-1);
```

Above line will randomized one value below from the list size.

Comment: Worked perfectly...Thanks so much

Comment: change the int index = rand.nextInt(list.size()-1); to int index = rand.nextInt(list.size()-89); and its not working

Answer (score 1):

The general algorithm would be to put boys and girls into a list, then use `Collections.shuffle(arrayList);`
to randomize the order.

 After that you can just call `list.remove(0)` for each seat you are assigning to.

Answer (score 1):

For the current code you have you have to get a random for a boy and then a random for a girl.

The error is because if the random gives you the size of the list, you would be trying to remove the last element twice.

Now, your code will give you 45 seats for girls and 45 to boys. To solve it use two if statements inside the while

```
       if(list.size()>10){
//get a random for a boy and then a random for a girl
}else{
//get a random for a girl
}
```

Comment: no. after remove one element from the list other are shifted down by one. if you look at oracle doc you can see this - **Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).**

Comment: you´re correct but that is why he is getting the error. He uses the same index to remove two elements, if the random gives him the last index, let's say 9(list size being 10). Once it removes for the second time he will be trying to remove again index 9, which no longer exists as the list's size is now 9

Comment: yeah.. yeah. When it come to the last index.